# Is there an SQLAlchemy equivalent of django-evolution?

Tags: python, database, django, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-migrate

All I want is to have a workflow somewhat similar to:

1. Add django_evolution to the INSTALLED_APPS for your project
2. Run ./manage.py syncdb
3. Make modifications to the model files in your project
4. Run ./manage.py evolve --hint --execute

Which is super simple and even though it doesn't support advanced features (like multiple databases) it does know how to add/remove columns which is a common use case.

sqlalchemy-migrate has an insanely complex workflow in comparison and both tutorials ([1](http://www.karoltomala.com/blog/?p=633), [2](http://caneypuggies.alwaysreformed.com/wiki/DevelopingWithMigrations)) referenced by the docs are either outdated or irrelevant.

Comment: I didn't know django-evolution. How does it compare to django-south ?

Comment: At the time I used django_evolution (south didn't yet exist) and I was very pleased. For specifics see http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/Alternatives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you already tried your hand on DJango :). These are the functionality right now not available with current SQLAlchemy. Suggested by @madjar you can use development version of Alembic or you can use [sqlalchemy-migrate](http://code.google.com/p/sqlalchemy-migrate/). Relevant [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300948/add-column-to-sqlalchemy-table) is already in stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

The creator of SQLAlchemy recently started working on [Alembic](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/alembic/). While it's still young (version 0.1), it may suits your needs.