# Python/SQL: move column in table A to table B

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

I have connected to a sql database through python using sql alchemy. I have a table called A and another table called B. The data from A and B comes from table F.

```
         **A**                         **B**
C1  C2  C3  C4  C5             D1    D2    D3   D4   D5
```

I was wondering if it is possible to take column C5 and insert it into table B such that table B looks like:

```
       **B**
D1  D2  D3  D4  D5  C5
```

I haven't come across any direct methods to do this. Has anyone figured out a way to approach this?

Comment: Do you want to change the database schema or select results from two tables?

Comment: All the elements in Table A and Table B come from a table F. I just want to copy C5 in table A and move it to table B

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy doesn't support modifying tables after creation.

[add column to SQLAlchemy Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300948/add-column-to-sqlalchemy-table)

This is referred to as database migration (SQLAlchemy doesn't support migration out of the box). You can look at using sqlalchemy-migrate to help in these kinds of situations, or you can just ALTER TABLE through your chosen database's command line utility,

Comment: [`alembic`](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is worth looking into if database schema changes are needed.