# How to update models.py when I add a new column with an ORM?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, orm, sqlalchemy-migrate

I'm fairly new to Python and ORMs and I have a pretty specific question. To handle SQL, a Python ORM needs to have models defined, likely in a file called `models.py`, right?

Now, when I want to automatically create a new *column* when I add content to a table how do I avoid updating `models.py` manually every time?

To give you some context: I have a db with the tables `Persons`, `Publications` and `Articles`. I would like to create a table that takes an ID from `Persons` as a new *column* and then fills its rows with all the IDs of `Publications` that the Person is writing for (related via `Articles`).

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300948/add-column-to-sqlalchemy-table) question [Damian Brecht](https://stackoverflow.com/users/534476/demian-brecht) points to [sqlalchemy-migrate](http://sqlalchemy-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.1/changeset.html) but I don't get how you keep the definition of the models updated, since every column is a line of code in `models.py`...

Comment: The models drive the database, not the other way around. When you need a new row or table, you make the changes to the models and either run a migration or generate a new database from your defined models.

Comment: "The models drive the databse, not the other way around." - Thanks, that did it for me. Guess I will have to look into migration then