# Should I drop_all() each time when I want to add a new column in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a simple website using Flask.
When I added `time` field to the `Td` class I got

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
>
> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table td
>   has no column named time

```
 class Td(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        text = db.Column(db.String(271), nullable=False)
        date = db.Column(db.String())
        time = db.Column(db.String())
```

I suppose that in production when you manage a big project it's not an option to `drop_all()` the whole `db` each time you add new column. 
Is there a proper way to add a new column?

Comment: here is something that may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300948/add-column-to-sqlalchemy-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Flask- Migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

It can be used to make schema changes to your database without deleting existing data.