# How to add column to existing Table? in Flask SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask SqlAclchemy table called User:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
```

i have now edited it and added this line;`favCol = db.Column(db.String(12))`

how do i update the table for it to recognize this new colum when i add a new user?
At the moment when i create a User like `User(username="bob",favCol="red")`
it gives me an error:

```
TypeError: 'favCol' is an invalid keyword argument for User
```

I have heard of solution with Migrate although i would prefer re a simpler solution if possible

Comment: Have you looked in the docs? They may have info there

Comment: Yea, i did not find anything. I also tried : ```db.update(User)``` in the python console

Comment: You wouldn't get the `invalid keyword argument for ...` error if you've added the `favCol = db.Column(...)` declaration to your model correctly. You should expect to get a `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError` error when sqlalchemy tries to write to the table and the column doesn't exist yet in the database.

Comment: You're unlikely to get answers with any better info than these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300948/add-column-to-sqlalchemy-table

Comment: Can i go to slite in the console and do something like : ALTER...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the data in the database getting erased.
You can do the following:

from terminal
if 'py' doesn't start python, try 'python'.
press enter after each of these commands

```
py
from projectdirectory import db
db.drop_all()
db.create_all()
```

If you care about your existing data, you need to use something like flask_migrate which uses alembic in order to help you do database migrations while maintaining your data.

Comment: Is there any solution without having my data erased?

Comment: Yes. refer to the last paragraph of my submitted answer. 
It's not a simple solution though. It's too complex to explain in a few lines here on how you could implement it. You'll have to research flask_migrate for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This answer will help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17243132/19280304

For flask-SQLAlchemy,  add this before the code

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
engine  = SQLAlchemy(app).engine
```