# How to add a column to an existing table in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pgadmin, sqlalchemy-migrate

I am working with SQLAlchemy in Python to perform column's CRUD operations on my database. I have successfully retrieved all the columns of a table using the following code:

```
def getItems(self):
    items = self.table.columns.keys()
    return items
```

However, I am facing difficulties while trying to add, update, and delete columns.

I have tried several methods, including executing raw SQL queries and using methods from SQLAlchemy's documentation, but none seem to work as expected.

Here's an example of a raw SQL query I tried:

```
query = f'ALTER TABLE {self.table} ADD {column_name} integer;'
connection.execute(query)
```

I also tried using SQLAlchemy's append_column method and migrate library as follows:

```
self.table.append_column(column: ColumnClause[Any], replace_existing: bool = False)

col = Column('new_column_name', String(20), default='foo')
col.create(self.table)
```

Although I don't receive any errors, the changes don't seem to persist. When I check the table in pgAdmin, the added columns are not there, even though they appear when I retrieve the columns using my getItems function.

I checked [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300948/add-column-to-sqlalchemy-table) but I didn't got my answer.

Could anyone point out what I might be doing wrong and how to properly add a column to an existing table in SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Did you commit the changes?

Comment: yes I did commit changes and checked it consistently.

Comment: If you are seeing the columns locally in your Python script, but they don't persist after the script has ended, or aren't visible to external apps like PgAdmin, the changes almost certainly haven't been committed, or the external apps haven't been refreshed.

Comment: thank you. I added session.commit() and it seemed to work with query execute method.